# Stimulsoft report is not showing its contents

Tags: asp.net-core, reporting, stimulsoft

I am using ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1 and trying to use a Stimulsoft report inside of the project. The report viewer is running but the contents of the report can not be seen.
May I know what can be the problem?

[Image of the result is.. please use the URL given below http://prntscr.com/rc1kou](http://prntscr.com/rc1kou)

[image: Image of the result is.. please use the URL given below]

Code is as follows:

### Controller

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Stimulsoft.Report;
using Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        


        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }

        public IActionResult GetReport()
        {
            // Create the report object
            StiReport report = new StiReport();
            report.LoadDocument(StiNetCoreHelper.MapPath(this, "Reports/TwoSimpleLists.mrt"));

            DataSet data = new DataSet("Demo");
            data.ReadXml(StiNetCoreHelper.MapPath(this, "Reports/Data/Demo.xml"));

            report.RegData(data);


            return StiNetCoreViewer.GetReportResult(this, report);
        }
        public IActionResult ViewerEvent()
        {
            return StiNetCoreViewer.ViewerEventResult(this);
        }
    }
}
```

### .CSHTML

```
@using Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc;

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

@Html.StiNetCoreViewer(new StiNetCoreViewerOptions()
{
    Actions =
    {
        GetReport = "GetReport",
        ViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent"
    }


})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `Load()` method instead of `LoadDocument()`to load the report template:

```
report.Load(StiNetCoreHelper.MapPath(this, "Reports/TwoSimpleLists.mrt"))
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use StiLicense.Key on your controller constructor